# Extract featureImportance from within a Pipeline

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

Models extending [DecisionTreeRegressionModel](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.regression.DecisionTreeRegressionModel) have a `featureImportances` method. If one builds models using [Pipelines](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel) one will have objects of type `Model[_]`.

How can one get `featureImportances` out of such pipelines for those models which support the method?

Answer (score 0):

If you know which stage of the pipeline the decision tree is in it is easy. For example, if the decision tree is in the third stage, you can do:

```
val featureImportances = pipelineModel
  .stages(2)  // The position in the pipeline of the stage you want
  .asInstanceOf[DecisionTreeRegressionModel]
  .featureImportances
```